# Updating CRM Reports - CRM 2011 Solution - What's happening under the covers?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, rdl

Trying to understand the expected behavior of CRM Reports w/ Report Server.

We have CRM 2011, UR 18.  We are an ISV developing a Managed Solution to sell to our customers.  The Managed Solution contains several reports (RDLs).  Want to understand how Updating works.

1) Import our Solution (Unmanaged) into a development Organization.  Solution contains Reports (RDLs).

2) Surf to the Report Server associated with this CRM installation.

3) Click on the Report name in the list, select 'Edit in Report Builder' from the drop down.

4) Edit the report.  Save it.

5) View the report in CRM.  Viola - we see our changes.

Later ---

6) Re-import another (later) version of the (unmanaged) Solution into CRM.  This copy of the Solution ZIP does *not* contain the RDL edits we made via Report Builder on our Report Server.

7) Surf into CRM, Reports.  View the report we previously edited.

Our edits remain in the report that we do see -- not what we expected.  We had thought that the re-import of the Solution ZIP would overwrite our edits to the RDL.  The behavior is as if the Report Server edits triumphed over the Solution contents.  Is this because we edited in Report Server directly (via Report Builder)?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Howard Hoffman

Answer (score 0):

This is basic functionality of CRM Solutions.  If you do not include a component in an unmanaged solution file, then that component will not be updated - it will remain exactly as it was before the solution import.  Remember, the solution file is just a container that has a bunch of references to components.
The way to revert to an old version of a report is to export that report before making the change, and then re-import THAT solution when you want to revert it.

Comment: The Report is actually part of our named, unmanaged, Solution.  That's why we expected the Import to overwrite the RDL.

Comment: so importing your report via solution does not change what exists in the target environment?  aka report A version 1 (A1) should be overwritten by version A2, in your solution file, but after importing, it stays version A1?
I assume publishing all customizations is part of your import process, right?

Comment: That is right.  In our case, we update the SSRS version and then Import.  The version in the Solution ZIP is "older" than what is in SSRS - but we figured that the Solution ZIP would win.  It doesn't.  This is quite puzzling.

Comment: In that case, I agree, it is quite puzzling, I misunderstood your original post.